# How to get a secret into a pytest test?

Tags: pytest

Say I have a pytest module with some test functions. In order to run the tests, the test functions need to have a Personal Access Token. I want to run these tests in a CI process in Azure DevOps. I can store the PAT as a secret variable in the Pipeline defintion, but the question is, how do I pass this secret to the test functions when running `pytest`?

### EDIT

I can read this from a file, and in the pipeline before running `pytest` I can format this file, but I don't like this approach so much.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you add the secret into the pipeline (which should have restricted access) and store it as a file or pass it as an argument? Then you would either need to read the file contents or implement a arg parser that would only run in the CI.

Comment: needing a secret to run tests seems like very poor design -- but you could use a file, an environment variable, or all sorts of ways to inject

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a pipeline but here's how you could do it.

First create your secrets in your desired key vault. I have created an app using Python and the Azure sdk which lets you create **multiple** secrets in a key vault very easily - https://github.com/TechyTish/AzurePy/blob/main/create-azure-secrets-README.md

lets say your secrets are stored as (**secretName**: **secretValue**):

- example1: 1234
- example2: hello567

...
etc

```
#filename: example.json

    "SOME_KEY_NAME1": "{#exampleOne#}",
    "SOME_KEY_NAME2": "{#exampleTwo#}",
```

Create a YAML pipeline which will have 2 tasks:

1. Extract keyvault secrets
2. Replace the .json key values with the secrets

```
#filename: azure-pipeline.yml

# Azure Key Vault
# Download Azure Key Vault secrets
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    connectedServiceName: # Azure subscription - you will need to create an service connection in the repo which has access policies to the keyvault
    keyVaultName: # Name of existing key vault
    secretsFilter: '*' # Downloads all secrets for the key vault
    runAsPreJob: true # Runs before the job starts
```

Underneath the previous task add another one.
This looks for any key value with the **{#** pre-fix and **#}** suffix in the **.json file** and the variables (below) after this task will replace the value in the .json file with the value of the secrets you assigned it.

```
#filename: azure-pipeline.yml

- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    targetFiles: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/codepath/jsonFileName.json"
    encoding: "auto"
        writeBOM: true
        verbosity: "detailed"
        actionOnMissing: "warn"
        keepToken: false
        tokenPrefix: "{#"
        tokenSuffix: "#}"
      displayName: Perform variable substitution in json file
- script: echo "$(<folderName/example.json)" #open json file in the terminal to show the changes

#.json value: point to secret name
variables:
  exampleOne: $(example1)
  exampleTwo: $(example2)
#....
#etc
```

Run the pipeline (tick the box for debugging) and your output of .json file should be:

```
#filename: example.json

    "SOME_KEY_NAME1": "1234",
    "SOME_KEY_NAME2": "hello567"
#....
#etc
```

This way the only time your secrets are revealed is when the pipeline is run on whichever host agent (virtual machine) you use.